# Big Oh confusion

Tags: big-o

I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate tight upper and lower bounds for algorithms. Why is the big oh of this equal to log(n)? Please explain in detail.

```
int count = 0
for (int a = 1; a < N; a = a * 2)
    for (int b = 1; b < N; b = b * 2)
        count++
    end for
end for
```

Answer (score 2):

The two loops are independent of each other, so we simply multiply together the complexities to obtain the overall complexity.  Each loop is `O(lgN)`, since at each step of the loops the counter is halved.  Therefore, the overall running time is `O(lgN*lgN) = O(lgN^2)`.

Comment: Hopefully I have turned your Big O into a smile: `:-O --> :-)`